# How to highlight all words in hindi text with regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am using using code with regular expression

```
 $title =  preg_replace("/\b(".preg_quote($searchword).")\b/i", '<span class="highlight_txt">\1</span>', $title);
```

and

```
$title = preg_replace("/\w*?".preg_quote($searchword)."\w*/i", "<span class='highlight_txt'>$0</span>", $title);

It is working properly for english but not for hindi string
```

e.g. for searching "ह"  look like this

तर**ह** के लाभ मिलते **ह**ैं

i want result

**तरह** के लाभ मिलते **हैं**

In english its proper working. e.g for searching h

**the** Indian **leadership**

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` or `\p{L}` won't match **मात्रा** part of `हैं`. It will only match `ह` leaving **मात्रा** unmatched.

You can use `[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]` instead to match any surrounding non-space, non-punctuation character.

```
/[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*?ह[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*/u
```

Modifier `/u` is for unicode support.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU8bD3/1)

**Code:**

```
$title = 'तरह के लाभ मिलते हैं';
$searchword = 'ह';

$title = preg_replace('/[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*?'.preg_quote($searchword).'[^\p{Zs}\p{P}]*/u',
         "<span class='highlight_txt'>$0</span>", $title);

//=> <span class='highlight_txt'>तरह</span> के लाभ मिलते <span class='highlight_txt'>हैं</span>
```